# Database only fetching first variable

Tags: php, sql, database, variables, pdf

This php is populated by a form posting variables to it. Once it has the car model it should be collecting data from the database and storing each variable for use further down the code. This is used alongside another database so I would rather populate each var list before moving ahead.

The problem is, the database is only collecting the first variable and none of the following variables. How can I call all variables and hold them there for use in the html below.

*eg. The client selects the car model, submits and the form sends the model to this code where the database should collect more information about the car for use in a automatically generated PDF brochure.*

Thanks for your help!!

```
//database, table CARS and store variables 
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "blah", "blah");
mysql_select_db("car_db", $conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE modelname = '$carmodel'" or die(mysql_error());  
                $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql, $conn); 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) 

//create variables from database entry
$dbbrand = $row['brandname'];
$dbseries = $row['series'];
$dbprice = $row['price'];
$dbseats = $row['seats'];
$dbtype = $row['type'];
$dbcolor = $row['color'];

// -------------------- HTML CONTENT -------------------- //

$html = "   
<body>
    <!--Print Wrap Start-->
    <div id=\"content\">

        <!--Header with logo-->
        <div id=\"div-head\"><div id=\"div-head\"><span class=\"important\">". $dbbrand ."</span></div></div>


        <!--start relative container-->
        <div id=\"div-1\"><span class=\"important\">". $dbseries ."</span>
```

Comment: The code you posted contains at least two syntax errors. Is this a direct copy-and-paste? If so, do you get errors when you run it?

Comment: Yeah this is mostly a direct copy paste, the only thing I replaced is the variable names and removed the db connection passwords. I don't receive any errors only missing variables for each following the first. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your syntax is copied as stated above, you need to put braces "{" and "}" around your variable assignments.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE modelname = '$carmodel'" or die(mysql_error());  
                $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql, $conn); 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {      <----- here

//create variables from database entry
$dbbrand = $row['brandname'];
$dbseries = $row['series'];
$dbprice = $row['price'];
$dbseats = $row['seats'];
$dbtype = $row['type'];
$dbcolor = $row['color'];

}    <---- here
```

Comment: That did the job, simple but annoying. Cheers!

"I'll test this out now. Thanks for your help and fast reply!"

Comment: to help you understand why it was a problem in the first place, you need to know that while loops, for loops and if statements all don't require the braces { } to work BUT if you don't use the braces, it only uses the next line for it's loop condition. so puting the braces around all your assignments fixed the problem

Comment: also, stop using mysql_query. you should at least be using mysqli or pdo. you will have problems upgrading in the future because mysql_query is already being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) 
//create variables from database entry
$dbbrand = $row['brandname'];
```

That code assigns a record from the result set into the $row variable, which in only used to assign the current value into the `$dbbrand` variable below the loop.

The while loop only controls one line of code and that is `$dbbrand = $row['brandname'];`. You need to wrap all the relevant lines of code below as a apart of the the while loop. Below I will demonstrate and correct for the other logical error in your code.

```
$data = array();
int a=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 

//create variables from database entry
$data[a]['dbbrand'] = $row['brandname'];
$data[a]['dbseries'] = $row['series'];
$data[a]['dbprice'] = $row['price'];
$data[a]['dbseats'] = $row['seats'];
$data[a]['dbtype'] = $row['type'];
$data[a]['dbcolor'] = $row['color'];
$a++;
}
```

If you want all values returned by the query, the adjustment to your code above will suffice.

Comment: Just note that if you need all the records returned by your query, the solution above is more accurate. and youre welcome